# Value Radical problem

Tags: radicals

Calculate the value of the radical: $$\left[\sqrt[{\sqrt[\sqrt3]{\sqrt3}}]{(3 \sqrt 3)^{  \sqrt[\sqrt3]{\sqrt3^{\sqrt3+1}}}}\right]^{\sqrt 3}$$

What is the tip to solve this problem? I think $(3\sqrt{3})^{9}$ is the answer

Attemp: I started thinking about replacing $ \sqrt {3} $ for $y$, but I can't develop much

Comment: Written out: $$\left[\sqrt[{\sqrt[\sqrt3]{\sqrt3}}]{(3 \sqrt 3)^{  \sqrt[\sqrt3]{\sqrt3^{\sqrt3+1}}}}\right]^{\sqrt 3}$$

Comment: @MishaLavrov ok

Comment: Please edit your query to show your work, or (at least) show your thought process.

Comment: That looks crazy.

Comment: @AdamRubinson but it is still a legitimate (unambiguous) math problem.

Comment: I never said it wasn’t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it.  But do it slowly and patiently.

$\left[\sqrt[\color{green}{{\sqrt[\sqrt3]{\sqrt3}}}]{(3 \sqrt 3)^{ \color{red}{ \sqrt[\sqrt3]{\sqrt3^{\sqrt3+1}}}}}\right]^{\color{purple}{\sqrt 3}}=$

$(3\sqrt 3)^{\frac {\color{purple}{\sqrt 3}\color{red}{ \sqrt[\sqrt3]{\sqrt3^{\sqrt3+1}}}}{\color{green}{{\sqrt[\sqrt3]{\sqrt3}}}}}=$

$(3\sqrt 3)^{(\sqrt 3)^{\color{purple}{1}-\color{green}{\sqrt 3}}\color{red}{\sqrt{3}^{\frac{\sqrt 3+1}{\sqrt 3}}}}=$

$(3\sqrt 3)^{\sqrt{3}^{1-\sqrt 3+ \frac {\sqrt 3+1}{\sqrt 3}}}=$

$(3\sqrt 3)^{\sqrt{3}^{1-\sqrt 3+ 1+\sqrt 3}}=$

$(3\sqrt 3)^{\sqrt 3^2}=$

$(3\sqrt 3)^3 =$

$(3^13^{\frac 12})^3=$

$(3^{1+\frac 12})^3 =$

$(3^{\frac 32})^3=$

$3^{\frac 92}=$

$3^{4\frac 12}=$

$3^4\sqrt 3=$

$81\sqrt 3$

Comment: Why $1 - \sqrt{3}$ in the third stage??

Comment: The purple $1$ comes from the $\color{purple}{\sqrt 3}=\color{purple}{\sqrt 3^1}$ in the numerator.  The green $\sqrt 3$ comes from the $\color{green}{\sqrt 3^{\sqrt 3}}$ in the denominator. Combining them we get $(\sqrt 3)^{\color{purple}1 - \color{green}{\sqrt 3}}$.